# How to activate error response only when no name attribute elements exist?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The following part of the Ajax code is in charge of displaying the error messages:

```
.done(function(data) {
    let res = JSON.parse(data);
    // si es true el estado
    if(res.status){
        $('.success').fadeIn();
        $('.success').html(res.message).delay(8000).fadeOut(8000);
        $(frm)[0].reset();
        $(frm).hide();
        setTimeout(function(){
            location.href = 'customer.php';
        },9000);
    } else {
        for (let name in res.message) {
            $('.error').remove();
            let msg = '<span class="error">' + res.message[name] + '</span>';
            $(msg).insertAfter($('[name=' + name + ']', '#ajaxData'));
            $('.error').fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut(5000);
        }
        $('.warning').fadeIn();
        $('.warning').html(res.message).delay(8000).fadeOut(8000);
    }
})
```

The first works, `if(res.status){` this activates the message `<div class="success"></div>` when everything is correct, the second part works `for (let name in res.message) {` because it activates the error message in each corresponding input:

```
<input type="text" name="cliente" value="">
<span class="error">The client is already registered.</span>
```

Those messages that are shown in each field are specified from here:

```
echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["nombre_cliente" =>"Please enter the customer's name to continue."]]);
```

But I need to show the error message `<div class="warning"></div>` correctly.

because so far the problem is that the error message is also activated with the class `<div class="warning"></div>` and, this should only be activated when the custom messages do not have an attribute or this parameter: `message'=> ["cliente"` that is to say activate this `<div class="warning"></div>` when the error messages to be emitted are in this way:

```
echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=>"<strong>We are sorry, but we are unable to process your request. Try again later.</strong>"]);
```

I have tried adding an `else` to it `for (let name in res.message)` as follows:

```
        for (let name in res.message) {
            $('.error').remove();
            let msg = '<span class="error">' + res.message[name] + '</span>';
            $(msg).insertAfter($('[name=' + name + ']', '#ajaxData'));
            $('.error').fadeIn().delay(5000).fadeOut(5000);
        } else {
            $('.warning').fadeIn();
            $('.warning').html(res.message).delay(8000).fadeOut(8000);
        }
```

But it doesn't work, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: There is no `else` for `for`, so that doesn’t make _any_ sense to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your json response `message` can be array or simple string so you can check if the `res.message` is array or not using [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) and depending on this show error or warning div.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var res = {
  'status': false,
  'message': "<strong>We are sorry, but we are unable to process your request. Try again later.</strong>"
}
//.done(function(data) {
//some other codes..
//check if the `res.message` is array
if (Array.isArray(res.message)) {
  for (let name in res.message) {
    //your other codes...
  }
} else {
  console.log("warning message")
  $('.warning').fadeIn();
  $('.warning').html(res.message).delay(8000).fadeOut(8000);

}
//})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="warning"></div>
```

Comment: It does not work, it deactivates the messages of `echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["nombre_cliente" =>"Please enter the customer's name to continue."]]);` based on: `for (let name in res.message) {}` and, the div is activated `<div class="warning"></div>` the div `<div class="warning"></div>` should only activate when there is only this condition: `echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=>"<strong>We are sorry, but we are unable to process your request. Try again later.</strong>"]);`

Comment: and, this other condition: `echo json_encode(['status'=> false, 'message'=> ["nombre_cliente" =>"Please enter the customer's name to continue."]]);` based on : `for (let name in res.message) {}` shows me the error messages in each input field of the corresponding form.

Comment: Attachment capturehttps://i.stack.imgur.com/RD6ep.png update the question

Comment: Hi, `["nombre_cliente" =>"Please ente..` is JSON array i.e `[{},{}..]` or normal array `[]` ? Also , can you show me output of `res` inside your done function ?

Comment: In these formats is the PHP json_encode code: https://ideone.com/Er0qNE And, so was the Ajax code: https://jsfiddle.net/61tnagx8/

Comment: change this `Array.isArray(res.message)` to `typeof (res.message) === 'object'` . Working code check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9ukswn0r/)